# Tokenizer for math expression

Tags: java, lexer

Using the `StreamTokenizer` I am writing a lexer that will tokenize a math expression.

As an input, I give the expression `(1+π)²(1−π)²+(5.3−-2)/6`. 
I expect it to be tokenized as 
`( 1 + π ) ² ( 1 - π ) ² + ( 5.3 − - 2 ) / 6` 
 
but I get `( 1 +π ) ² ( 1 -π ) ² + ( 5.3 −-2 ) / 6`.

I know I need to insert the multiplication operators in certain places of the output, will do it later.

```
/* s: The inputted expression */
public static String tokenize(String s)[] throws IOException
{
    StreamTokenizer tokenizer = new StreamTokenizer(new StringReader(s));
    tokenizer.parseNumbers();
    tokenizer.wordChars('a', 'z');
    tokenizer.wordChars('A', 'Z');
    tokenizer.wordChars('A', 'Z');
    tokenizer.wordChars(SQUARED, SQUARED); // the superscript 2
    tokenizer.wordChars(PI, PI);
    tokenizer.wordChars(SUB.charAt(0), SUB.charAt(0)); // subtract (takeaway)
    tokenizer.wordChars(NEG.charAt(0), NEG.charAt(0)); // negate
    tokenizer.wordChars('/', '/');
    tokenizer.wordChars('*', '*');
    tokenizer.wordChars('+', '+');
    tokenizer.ordinaryChar(',');
    tokenizer.ordinaryChar('/');    // do not consider / as comment start

    ArrayList<String> tokBuf = new ArrayList<>();
    while (tokenizer.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF) {
        switch (tokenizer.ttype) {
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER:
                tokBuf.add(String.valueOf(tokenizer.nval));
                break;
            case StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD:
                tokBuf.add(tokenizer.sval);
                break;
            default:
                tokBuf.add(String.valueOf((char) tokenizer.ttype));
        }
    }
    String ret[] = new String[tokBuf.size()];
    ret = tokBuf.toArray(ret);

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: `StringTokenizer` will treat `--` as a single token. You're using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @EJP I used two different subtraction signs, one smaller one bigger; they are different codepoints

Comment: Regardless, @EJP is correct.  `StreamTokenizer` is the wrong tool.  It is very limited in the syntax it can handle.  Also, the Javadoc is not very clear and there is a strong indication it will not handle code points above `0x00FF` correctly (or at all?).  You will be much better off writing your own simple state-driven lexer where you can tailor the behavior to your requirements.  Otherwise you're just trying to use a blunt screwdriver where a fine woodworking chisel is needed.

Comment: Was pretty much going to say the same thing.  `StreamTokenizer` or the other two tokenizer classes in Java are just too simple.  They're cute ideas but only intended really for simple problems, maybe students or something.  If you want to use a tool rather than write your own from scratch, look at `Antlr 4`  http://www.antlr.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
enum TokType {
    FIRST,
    OPERAND,
    OPERATOR,
    LPAREN,
    RPAREN,
}

boolean shouldMultBeEmitted(TokType tt)
{
    return tt == TokType.OPERAND || tt == TokType.RPAREN;
}

public ArrayList<String> tokenize(String in)
{
    TokType prevTok = TokType.FIRST; /* keep track of the type of the prev. tok, so
                                        we know when to insert a mult. sign */

    String regex = "(?<=[-−+*/()])|(?=[-−+*/()])";
    String toks[] = in.split(regex);

    /* the string has been tokenized; insert any needed multiplication signs */
    ArrayList<String> ret = new ArrayList<>();

    for (String x : toks) {
        if (isNumeric(x) || x.equals("Ans") || x.equals("π")) {
            if (shouldMultBeEmitted(prevTok))
                ret.add("*");

            prevTok = TokType.OPERAND;
        }
        else if (x.equals(LPAREN)) {
            if (shouldMultBeEmitted(prevTok))
                ret.add("*");

            prevTok = TokType.LPAREN;
        }
        else if (x.equals(RPAREN))
            prevTok = TokType.RPAREN;
        else if (isOperator(x))
            prevTok = TokType.OPERATOR;

        ret.add(x);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Courtesy to https://stackoverflow.com/a/15983144/2469027 for providing the RegEx.

Exercise to the reader: Insert the multiplication sign after the squared (`²`) operator, so the example you provided in the question would be correct.